# Silverlight UpdateTarget() workaround for BindingExpression

Tags: silverlight, binding

Can anyone suggest a way to create in Silverlight a workaround for UpdateTarget() method that exists in WPF? Removing the existing binding that exists on the DP and setting the value manually is not an option for me. Thanks

Comment: What is your reason for needing UpdateTarget()?  Depending on the reason there could be different workarounds.

Comment: I have a binding in my XAML and we are porting an existing application to Silverlight and using the same XML/code behind files. As far as the existing WPF code goes I have the following expression:
BindingExpression expression = someTextBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty); 
expression.UpdateTarget();

This is the existing code, and I would create an extension method for this is SL not to use #if WPF directives... The idea is to have a method that behaves like BindingExpression.UpdateTarget() in WPF.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try something like this. Replace ImageBlobMember with your XAML control's x:Name/Name and replace Image.SourceProperty with the appropriate value depending on the type of control.

```
BindingExpression bindExp =
 ImageBlobMember.GetBindingExpression(System.Windows.Controls.Image.SourceProperty);
Binding bind = bindExp.ParentBinding;
ImageBlobMember.SetBinding(System.Windows.Controls.Image.SourceProperty, bind);
```

Comment: This is how I did it in the end but I had to make sure I was checking for nulls

Comment: Thanks! I was searching for a while, and this was the only option that was functionally sufficient to simulate the missing `BindingExpression.UpdateTarget()` method in Silverlight 5.